# PickerView Delegate Causing Crash

Tags: ios, delegates, crash, uipickerview, modalviewcontroller

I am dismissing a modal view controller whom is the `delegate` of a `UIPickerView`.

When I dismiss the view using

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

My app crashes, but only when the `UIPickerView` is showing, and currently the first responder.

I found the the cause of the crash to be a Zombie, this method, `[UIPicker _updateSelectedRows]` is showing in my instruments as the issue.

I am able to fix the issue by setting the UIPicker delegate and dataSource to nil prior to dismissing the view controller.

I have never needed to do this before, is there something I'm missing?

Here is a bare bones of the presenting view, presented in a modal segue. When you dismiss this using the IBAction, it will cause the crash

```
@interface VTSecViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *catPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *catItems;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pickerTF;

@end

@implementation VTSecViewController

- (IBAction)dismpress:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.catItems = @[@"one", @"two"];
    self.catPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.pickerTF.inputView = self.catPicker;
    self.catPicker.delegate = self;
    self.catPicker.dataSource = self;
    [self.pickerTF becomeFirstResponder];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

#pragma mark PickerView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.catItems count];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.pickerTF.text = self.catItems[row];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.catItems[row];
}


@end
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016348/set-delegates-to-nil-under-arc) helps clear up a few things

Comment: How are you presenting  UIPickerview?? in actionsheet or some other viewcontroller?

Comment: as an inputView of a UITextField

Comment: Than you should use     `[ self.categoryTF resignFirstResponder];` for dismissing pickerview.

Comment: Yeah, I am using  [self.view endEditing:YES]; prior to dismissing, but still get crash 1 in 5, only way to ensure no crash was setting delegates to nil.

Comment: Do you execute setUpCatPicker more than once? Just wondering if you should only set `self.catPicker` if its nil? (clutching at straws though)

Comment: No just once, having TF delegate with normal keyboard has no issues, must be a picker thing. Strange that if I embed in a Nav Controller the crash doesn't happen. As per my answer, option 3 in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737186/position-of-navigation-bar-for-modal-view-ios7/20967695#20967695

Answer (score 3):

delegate (in this case your view controller) is supposed to give the information to pickerview on things like titles / row count / whattodo when you tap etc.. when you dismiss the controller while picker is still on the view. pickerview does not know that your controller died & it will keep asking the delegate about those information, hence -> crash.

when you set the delegate & datasource to nil. it will let know the pickerview that your delegate does not exist anymore so you wont get the crash.

sidenote : go to the delegate & datasource property in documentation it shows

```
@protocol UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate;

NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UIPickerView : UIView <NSCoding, UITableViewDataSource>

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<UIPickerViewDataSource> dataSource;                // default is nil. weak reference
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<UIPickerViewDelegate>   delegate;                  // default is nil. weak reference
```

you can see the properties are "assign" (weak) and not "retain" (strong). hence when you dismiss the delegate & datasource uipickerview does not make any impact on the reference count of the delegate & it deallocates. it would have been a different case if this had been retain / strong. you should probably check out memory management topic on apple documentation on how these work. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html. delegates are weak references almost all the time.

Comment: But that doesn't always happen. I have this problem in one project, I'm trying to isolate it and reproduce in an app created from scratch, to no avail.

Comment: Furthermore, I cannot understand how a weak property can cause a zombie situation – it should safely nullify itself.

Comment: i was trying to explain why delegates/datasource must  be kept weak/assign properties and not strong properties. I think you misunderstood.

Comment: My bad then. Actually, I think the real cause of trouble is those properties are `assign` (i.e. unsafe_unretained), not `weak`. Combined with the fact that iOS often keeps holding +1 references to subviews of a deallocated view controller's view (for whatever reason) – ...

Comment: I think you should better read a little more about uiviewcontroller & uiview relationship. UIViewController has a strong property UIView (so controller cannot survive without a view), where on the otherhand a UIView has only a weak/ delegate reference to UiViewController. (meaning uiview can survive well without a controller class). When ever you add a view-A to another view-B, that view-B's controller/class would +1 the view-A's reference count but this will not affect controllers reference count. thats why originally you can see the pickerview in  UI, but the controller/delegate is dead.

Comment: I believe most of the statements in your last comment doesn't make much sense, but this is a wrong place to discuss that. And thank you for trying to help.