# How to replace new location coordinates in current location coordinates in MKMapView in swift

Tags: swift, coordinates, mkmapview

I am using map in Two viewcontrollers

Initially in first viewcontroller i am getting current location in map..

in second viewcontroller i am getting new location coordinates, which i am sending to firstview controller using delegate..  but here how to replace the delegate method coordinates with current location coordinates in first view controller

**first view controller code**: here in delegate method i am successfully having new location coordinates which i need replace with current location

in `userDidEnterInformation`delegate method i am getting all values from 2nd view controller

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
class ProfileAddressViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, DataEnteredDelegate {
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var latitude: Double?
var logitude: Double?

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func userDidEnterInformation(info: DataEnteredModelSave) {
    print("map address viewcontroller data \(info)")
    self.pincodeField.text = info.pinCode
    self.cityField.text = info.cityField
    self.latitude = info.zLatitude
    self.self.logitude = info.zLongitude
    print("new map address viewcontroller data info lat long \(self.latitude) \(self.logitude)")
}
    
@IBAction func submitButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    
    let userLocation :CLLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation
    latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    logitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print("error in reverseGeocode")
        }
        let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
                    
        if placemark.count>0{
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            let placemarkDictonary: NSDictionary=placemark.addressDictionary as! NSDictionary
            self.pincodeField.text=placemarkDictonary["ZIP"] as? String
            self.cityField.text=placemarkDictonary["City"] as? String
        }
    }
    
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: logitude!)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    myAnnotation.title = "Current location"
    mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
}
}
```

please help me to add delegate method latitude and longitude in `locationManager didUpdateLocations`

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916504/how-to-stop-updating-location-once-i-get-current-location

Comment: @DharmeshKheni i have added `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` but nothing changed, why? any other solution..

Comment: how you used it?

Comment: Can you share demo project?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni i have added only this post related code in github: https://github.com/SwiftSamples/MapcoordinateBug

Comment: @DharmeshKheni in 1st vc tap on continue will move to 2ndvc here if u search or move the map ten its location will be changing and once tap on confirm... all textfield values are updatng with new values but map showes current location only, why?

Comment: ok let me check that

Comment: @DharmeshKheni please update the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `userDidEnterInformation` with below code:

```
func userDidEnterInformation(info: DataEnteredModelSave) {
    print("map address viewcontroller data \(info)")
    self.pincodeField.text = info.pinCode
    self.streetField.text = info.streetField
    self.cityField.text = info.cityField
    self.latitude = info.zLatitude
    self.logitude = info.zLongitude
    print("map address viewcontroller data info lat long \(self.latitude) \(self.logitude)")
    
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() //stop updating location when you got data from delegate
    
    let userLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: latitude!, longitude: logitude!)
    
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print("error in reverseGeocode")
        }
        let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
        
        if placemark.count>0{
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            print(placemark.locality!)
            print(placemark.administrativeArea!)
            print(placemark.country!)
            let placemarkDictonary: NSDictionary=placemark.addressDictionary as! NSDictionary
            self.pincodeField.text=placemarkDictonary["ZIP"] as? String
            self.cityField.text=placemarkDictonary["City"] as? String
            self.plotField.text=placemarkDictonary["Name"] as? String
            self.streetField.text=placemarkDictonary["Street"] as? String
            self.appormentNoField.text=placemarkDictonary["SubThoroughfare"] as? String
            self.colonyField.text=placemarkDictonary["SubLocality"] as? String
            self.landmarkField.text=placemarkDictonary["SubThoroughfare"] as? String
        }
    }
    
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: logitude!)
    
    //Assign data to map again with new location
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, logitude!)
    myAnnotation.title = "Current location"
    mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
}
```

I have added comments please check them.

**EDIT:** As per your second request if you want to show new coordinates on `NewZoomAddressViewController` first you need to pass coordinates to `NewZoomAddressViewController` in `submitButtonClicked` method like:

```
viewController.latestLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: self.latitude!, longitude: self.logitude!)
```

then in `NewZoomAddressViewController` declare new var

```
var latestLocation: CLLocation?
```

and remove other code which is related to user's current location and final code will look like:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
//import SwiftKeychainWrapper
protocol DataEnteredDelegate: class {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: DataEnteredModelSave)
}

class NewZoomAddressViewController: UIViewController {
       
    @IBOutlet weak var oneBtnContainerView: UIView!
    
    var latitudeZoom: Double?
    var logitudeZoom: Double?
    
    weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil
   
    var zipName: String?
    var localityName: String?
    var sublocalityName: String?
    var streetNumber: String?
    var streetName: String?
    
    
    let searchCont = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    
    let regionInMeters: Double = 10000
    var previousLocation: CLLocation?
    var latestLocation: CLLocation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("in Zoom map VC")
        
        mapView.delegate = self
        addressLabel.text = "\(self.sublocalityName!) \(localityName!) \(self.zipName!)"
        centerViewOnUserLocation()
        
    }
    @IBAction func backBtn(_ sender: Any) {
           self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
       }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=true
        
        
    }
    
    var viewController: UIViewController?
    
    
    
    @IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        
        guard
                     let zipName = zipName,
                     let sublocalityName = sublocalityName,
                     let localityName = localityName,
                     let lnatZ = latitudeZoom,
                     let longZ = logitudeZoom
      
                     else { return }
        let enteredData = DataEnteredModelSave(pinCode: zipName, streetField: sublocalityName, cityField: localityName, zLatitude: lnatZ, zLongitude: longZ)
                 delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(info: enteredData)
              
              self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = latestLocation {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    func getCenterLocation(for mapView: MKMapView) -> CLLocation {
        latitudeZoom = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude
      logitudeZoom = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude
        
       
        print("coordinates from zoom in func \(latitudeZoom), \(logitudeZoom)")
        
        return CLLocation(latitude: latitudeZoom!, longitude: logitudeZoom!)
        //print(CLLocation.self)
    }
}



extension NewZoomAddressViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    //    MARK:- Search Address
    @IBAction func searchLocationButton(_ sender: Any) {
       // let searchCont = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchCont.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchCont.searchBar.backgroundColor = .blue
        present(searchCont, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //create the search request
        let searchReq = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        searchReq.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
        let activeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchReq)
        activeSearch.start { (response, error) in
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            if response == nil{
                print("error")
            }
            else{
                //remove annotation
                //let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
               // self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotations as! MKAnnotation)
                //getting data
                let lat = response?.boundingRegion.center.latitude
                let long = response?.boundingRegion.center.longitude
                //create annotation
                //let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                self.annotation.title = searchBar.text
                self.annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!, long!)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotation)
                //zooming annotation
                let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!, long!)
                let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
                self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                
                
                // Add below code to get search address
                let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
                let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)
                      geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:
                          {
                              placemarks, error -> Void in

                              // Place details
                              guard let placeMark = placemarks?.first else { return }

                              // Location name
                            
                            self.zipName = placeMark.postalCode
                            self.localityName = placeMark.locality
                            self.sublocalityName = placeMark.subLocality
                            self.streetNumber = placeMark.subThoroughfare
                            self.streetName = placeMark.thoroughfare
                           

                      })
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}


extension NewZoomAddressViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        let center = getCenterLocation(for: mapView)
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        
        guard let previousLocation = self.latestLocation else { return }
        
        guard center.distance(from: previousLocation) > 50 else { return }
        self.previousLocation = center
        
        
        
        let userLocation :CLLocation = center as CLLocation
        latitudeZoom = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        logitudeZoom = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        
        
        print("snajxhdwuidhwiuqhdxiqwjmdio \(latitudeZoom), \(logitudeZoom)")
        
        
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(center) { [weak self] (placemarks, error) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            if let _ = error {
                //TODO: Show alert informing the user
                return
            }
            
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                //TODO: Show alert informing the user
                return
            }
            
            
           self.streetNumber = placemark.subThoroughfare ?? ""
            self.streetName = placemark.thoroughfare ?? ""
            
            
            print("street number of zoom map \(self.streetName)")
            
            self.localityName = placemark.locality ?? ""//locality
            self.sublocalityName = placemark.subLocality ?? ""//locality
            self.zipName = placemark.postalCode ?? ""//locality
            
            
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.addressLabel.text = "\(self.streetNumber ?? "") \(self.streetName ?? "") \(self.sublocalityName ?? "") \(self.zipName ?? "") \(self.localityName ?? "")"
                print("zzooom map location label \(self.addressLabel.text)")
   
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, actually when continue in `ProfileAddressViewController ` need to update that location coordinates in in `NewZoomAddressViewController`  as well.. there i need to pass that coordinates to JSON like its label update with textfields

Comment: Hello how to update new location coordinates in `NewZoomAddressViewController ` here below label is updating with new value but how to update map coordinates

Comment: so when you again go to `NewZoomAddressViewController` you want to show previously selected coordinates on map?

Comment: yeah.. now only label updating with new values now the map also need to update with new coordinates

Comment: you need pass `latitude` and `logitude` to `NewZoomAddressViewController` when you tap continue

Comment: And always show that location on `NewZoomAddressViewController `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216401/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-swiftios).

Comment: which address coming from `ProfileAddressViewController` need to show that address in `NewZoomAddressViewController`  no need of current location

Comment: if i send coordinates from continue then coordinates not showing in `NewZoomAddressViewController `

Comment: I will post an answer soon